# nopCommerce: Customize Home Page By Coding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-themes

I am new in `nopCommerce`.

I want change the position of `Mega Menu` by changing the view portion of nopCommerce. In which `Controller` Home Page View is situated?

Comment: Are you using any theme or plugin?

Comment: I am using Pavilion theme.

Comment: You can find code of view page on `\Presentation\Nop.Web\Views\Shared\_Root.cshtml` and find accordingly in your theme.

Comment: I want to take the mega menu under my search input.

Comment: Do you have a megamenu plugin?

Comment: Yes I have mega menu plugin.

Comment: Check in the configuration of that plugin, may be there is setting for it.

Comment: There is no option to change the location of mega menu. Do you know where I can change the plugins?

Comment: See [this](http://admin-demos.nop-templates.com/admin/MegaMenuAdmin/MenuEdit/1) may be it from `Widget zone`

Comment: I saw this but this can't help me to solve my problem. Please tall me where is the plugins code in my solution?

Comment: You clould have just view pages and DLLs of that plugin which located in `Nop.web > Plugins > sevenspike megamenu`

Comment: And we don't have a theme and plugin so, we're not able to tell you, where exactly you have to make change. In this case you can ask to nopTemplete team.

Comment: I have a folder under Nop.Web > Plugins > Bin. Bin is empty.

Comment: That is not located in `bin`, find in `Nop.Web > Plugins >` there should be a folder for megamenu plugin

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using mega menu plugin if yes then find the mega menu code files in plugins/{megamenu}/views and explore to find the code to change

Answer (score 0):

see _Root.cshtm of your current theme. If you do not use theme see Views folder. Better copy _root.cshtml to THemes\DefaultClean and fix there

lines of code for menu

@Html.Action("TopMenu", "Catalog")